# Sum up selected rows in Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Is there any way to sum up a merge datatable by selected rows only?
For example:

[image: Example Table]

I just want to add up the `amt_A` of row 1 and row 4, then the sum up value will store into a new column.

**Edit** The sum up value will add into fifth row with column name `Total_amt_A`

Comment: What database are you using? Most of them have a syntax for that: ``SUM rowName AS newRowNameForYourSum``

Comment: provide the expected output in tabular format This is vague `store into a new column.`

Comment: New column doesn't have value for all Rows, what does other Rows contain (a default value)

Comment: @MioBambino I had retrieved the data from database and store in a datatable

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I want to sum up certain row from my datatable, some rows might be null